# NoReverseMatch Django url parameter passing

Tags: django, url, django-templates, parameter-passing, django-urls

I am trying to pass a string parameter to a url and I keep getting this error.

```
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

on this url

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/<str:filter>/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
]
```

root urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('user/', include('users.urls')),
    path('', include('app.urls')), # dashboard comes from here
]
```

this is how I pass the parameter
`href="{% url 'dashboard' 'create_time' %}"`

view

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request, filter):

    data = []

    context = {
        'title': 'Dashboard',
        'records': data,
    }
    return render(request, 'app/common/dashboard.html', context)
```

Comment: Try `href="{% url 'app:dashboard' 'create_time' %}"`

Comment: please add the concerned  view and html(not just that one line)